# Use of assert statement in test cases written in python

Tags: python

I have gone through many source code of functional test cases written in python. Many of the code uses assert for testing equality, why so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most test runners, a test failure is indicated by raising an exception - which is what the `assert()` function does if its argument evaluates to `False`.

Thus `assert(1 == 0)` will fail, and abort that specific test with an `AssertionError` exception. This is caught by the test framework, and the test is marked as having failed.

The framework/test-runner then moves on to the next test.